# (Error starting container: API error (500) Hyperledger

Tags: go, docker, ibm-cloud, blockchain, hyperledger

I am using bluemix network to deploy and test my custom chaincode( [link](https://github.com/tortuga90/chaincode/blob/master/test/test.go) to the chaincode). I'm using hte Swagger API to deploy, invoke and query my chaincode. The deploy and invoke work fine but when I try to query my chaincode, I keep getting the following error[image]
Following is the validating peer logs :
[image]

Is it some problem with my query code or network issue. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The error likely happened during the deploy phase (the logs just shows the query). The "deploy" being an asynchronous transaction returning an ID (just "submits" the transaction to be processed later) cannot indicate if the actual execution of the transaction will be successful or not. But the "query" request is synchronous and shows a failure.

Looking at the chaincode, the error is almost certainly due to the import and use of "github.com/op/go-logging" package. As the fabric only copies the chaincode and does not pick up its dependencies, that package is not available at deploy time.

Note that the same code will work when under "github.com/hyperledger/fabric" path as "github.com/op/go-logging" is available as a "vendor" package in that path.

To test this, try commenting out the import statement and all logging from the code (make sure "go build" works locally first with the changes).